# How to specify istanbul options for grunt.registerTask

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I am able to run istanbul to give me a report on my mocha testcases coverage, as follows,

```
./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec test/**/*_test.js
```

Now, I want to add this as part of my Gruntfile.js, so that I can make my build fail if the coverage is below certain percentage.

So I installed **grunt-istanbul-coverage** and added the following in the Gruntfile.js,

```
grunt.initConfig({
        jshint: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'index.js', 'lib/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            src: ['test/**/*_test.js'],
            options: {
                globals: ['chai'],
                timeout: 6000,
                ignoreLeaks: false,
                ui: 'bdd',
                reporter: 'spec'
            }
        },
        coverage: {
            options: {
                thresholds: {
                    'statements': 80,
                    'branches': 80,
                    'lines': 80,
                    'functions': 80
                },
                dir: 'coverage',
                root: 'test'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-istanbul-coverage');

    grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'mochaTest']);
    grunt.registerTask('codecoverage', ['coverage']);
```

When I run **grunt codecoverage**, it only runs for the top level test. How and where do I specify that I want to run it with `mocha -- -R spec test/**/*_test.js` ?